# Bootstrap 3 - Columns width divided equally without using col-md-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="column1"></div>
    <div class="column2"></div>
 </div>
```

column1 and column2 should be divided equally to take half the space.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="column1"></div>
    <div class="column2"></div>
    <div class="column3"></div>
 </div>
```

column1, column2 and column3 should be divided equally to take 1/3 of space.

Comment: Do you mean columns withing columns?

Comment: I updated the question to explain what I mean. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 (currently an alpha release) this is default behavior: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by looking at how Bootstrap 4 does this.

HTML:

```
<div class="auto-row form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <div class="form-group"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
div.auto-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;

  > div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Bootstrap 4 auto-layout columns..

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this available in Bootstrap 3.3.6?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. In Bootstrap 3, there is no way to divide the columns equally without specifying in the column class. You just have to divide by 12 and do it that way.